# Is it possible to use a variable at the end of "route.params." to catch several other "router.params"?

Tags: variables, vue.js, parameters, router, vue-router

I am using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) to, among other things, pass parameters between components. A part of my app has a child component repeated inside three other components. I'll only be using one parent component at a time.

The child shared component needs to access a parameter passed differently in each of the routes of the other three other components (in all of them the param is a String).

i.e.:
component1.vue is using:

```
this.$route.params.something
```

component2.vue is using:

```
this.$route.params.anothersomething
```

component3.vue is using:

```
this.$route.params.yetanothersomething
```

My question is: on the shared component, is there a way to access the last part of the path through a variable? something like this:

```
this.$route.params.{} //or
this.$route.params.${bar} //or
this.$route.params.*
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Why don't you pass it into the child component through the prop? Doing this through the router is not a good idea.

Comment: since I have the data already there, why not? in this case i need the data in a child component but in other situations the components relation is different. Anyway i think I found a simple way. just testing it now

Answer (score 0):

On the child component use:

```
  let info1 = this.$route.params;
  let info = info1[Object.keys(info1)[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Props.

In first parent component:

```
<SharedComponent :prop="$route.params.something"></SharedComponent>
```

In second parent component:

```
<SharedComponent :prop="$route.params.anothersomething"></SharedComponent>
```

In third parent:

```
<SharedComponent :prop="$route.params.yetanothersomething"></SharedComponent>
```